# Calculate prime numbers using threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have to calculate prime numbers between ranges by threads.
example program run

```
./myProg 100 250 4 //4 number of threads and 100 to 250 is range
```

I did basic part, what is the next step?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void* prime(void*);//calculate prime number for this thread between range x to y ???

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    if(argc!=4){
        cout<<"Must provide exactly 3 arguments"<<endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    pthread_t threads[(*argv[3])];

    cout<<"Prime numbers will be calculated by "<<(*argv[3])<<" threads"<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that pretty simply by using the Rabin-Miller primality tests on each value in each range. The Rabbin-Miller algorithm doesn't depend on the computation of primality for previous values, so all your threads may run in isolation without any communication between them.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test
- [Introduction to Algorithms](http://www.amazon.fr/Introduction-Algorithms-3e-ISE-Cormen/dp/0262533057/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1435144386&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+algorithms+cormen)